# Difference in converting objects to strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm wanting to convert an object to a string in JavaScript and I'm confused on which method I should use. I have a simple example below.

#### The first method

```
/\d+/g.toString()
```

#### The second method

```
/\d+/g + ''
```

Is there a difference between these two?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Implicit conversions are an important part of the language's practice, so it's perfectly normal to do it.

Comment: @dystroy: Ah, so that's why `[] + []` results in `""`, `{} + []` results in `0` and `{} + {}` results in `NaN`. I think I'll stick with Python :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker I don't pretend you don't have to stick to some readability principles. In fact, more than in other languages, an important part of the work of the coder should be dedicated to making its code obvious and natural, but that's not so hard.

Comment: @TimPietzcker should be `({} + [])` (`"[object Object]"`) -- you would never write actual code to have that in statement context where it results in `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second method additionally works with `null/undefined` and is not that unclear:

```
a.toString() //Fails with null/undefined

a + "" //Works with anything
```

You might also find other idioms such as `+a` useful, which is a much stricter `parseFloat`.

Comment: `+a` rather is a stricter `parseFloat`

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no difference, when an object must be converted to a string, the `toString` function is called.

More precisely, the `toPrimitive` conversion with hint "string" is applied, and it's defined  here in [the ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8) for an object.

Note that when you pass null or undefined (see [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)), only the addition scheme would work. That, along the reduced verbosity, explain why `toString` is rarely explicitly called in JavaScript. Implicit conversions are an important part of the language's practice, so it's perfectly normal to use this method, just as you often prefix a string with `+` to convert it to a number (i.e. `+'33'`) .

Answer (score 0):

Both are same. the second one will also call the `toString()`.